# Cannot serialize an object using XML Serializer having object names same in child object and sibling objects

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

If this is a repeating query, please suggest which has the exact reason for such case because I could not find any of it.

I am trying to serialize the following object to xml using xml serializer, but getting some exception.

```
[Serializable]
public class KAD
{
    public KAD()
    {
        StaffMembers = new List<StaffMember>();
        Jobs = new List<Job>();
        Tasks = new List<Task>();
    }
    public List<StaffMember> StaffMembers { get; set; }

    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}


public class Job
{
    public Job()
    {

    }
    public int? JobId { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
 }

public class Task
{
    public Task()
    {

    }
    public int? TaskId { get; set; }
    public string TaskTitle { get; set; }
}
```

And my StaffMember Class is something different namespace and having the child properties again but of same name i.e. Task and Job.

```
 public class StaffMember
 {
    public StaffMember()
    {
        Jobs = new List<Job>();
    }
    public int StaffMemberID { get; set; }        
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int? TaskId { get; set; }
    public string TaskTitle { get; set; }
    public bool? OverAllTaskCompetency { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ExpireyOfNextCompetencyOrLicenceForTask { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    public Job()
    {
        Tasks = new List<Task>();
    }

    public int? JobId { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }        
    public decimal? Rate { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to initialize serializer , it gives me an exception at this line:

```
 XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (KAD));
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: There was an error reflecting type 'KAD'. If anyone suggest the possible solution, will be greatly appreciated. One more thing, I cannot change the class names from both child and parent scope.

Comment: Check the inner exception to see what's the error why the serializer can't reflect the KAD type.

Comment: It says : {"There was an error reflecting property 'Jobs'."}

Comment: Then the inner exception must have an inner exception, recurse the exceptions until there is no more inner exceptions, that will be the root cause of it.

Comment: Yes, There was an inner exception inside inner exception.And that helped me to understand the actual issue. Actually the Job and Task class inside child and parent classes is available and that was causing issue. So found solution using adding attribute on parent classes like [XmlRoot("KAD_Job", Namespace = "root")]

Comment: Also, if the previous answers did not solved your problem and you post your own solution, then accept your own response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution for this problem.

By adding the namespace and name for the parent objects, serializer can differentiate them from the child objects. like parent Job and Task classes use attribute XmlRoot:

```
[XmlRoot("KAD_Job", Namespace = "root")]
public class Job
{
    public Job()
    {

    }
    public int? JobId { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string CraftCode { get; set; }
    public decimal? Rate { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot("KAD_TASK", Namespace = "root")]
public class Task
{
    public Task()
    {

    }
    public int? TaskId { get; set; }
    public string TaskTitle { get; set; }
}
```

And this worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To serialize nullable properties, you need to mark them as such, like so:

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
public int? JobId { get; set; }
```

Do you really need those properties to be nullable, though?

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will add the attribute to specify the nullable properties. And, Yes I need them even this is nullable for some business requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Add xml namespaces to your classes:

```
  [XmlType(TypeName = "Task",
      Namespace = "Tester.Staff")]
    public class Task
    {
        public int? TaskId { get; set; }
        public string TaskTitle { get; set; }
        public bool? OverAllTaskCompetency { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ExpireyOfNextCompetencyOrLicenceForTask { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType(TypeName = "Job",
         Namespace = "Tester.Staff")]
    public class Job
    {
        public Job()
        {
            Tasks = new List<Task>();
        }

        public int? JobId { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
        public decimal? Rate { get; set; }
        public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    }
```